# How do I find the index of an element in a Tuple if it exists?

Tags: stanza

Say I have this:

```
val index? = 
   label<Int|False> return:
     for (this in tuple, i in 0 to false) do:
       if this == that:
         return(i)
match(index?:Int):
  println("index was %_" % [index])
else: 
  println("not found")
```

Is there a cleaner or more idiomatic form to search a tuple and return the index of the item if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Yup! Just use this function:

```
val index = index-of(tuple, that)
```

It does exactly that. There's also an `index-when` function where you can plugin any predicate you want.

Patrick